# how to find 3d position of a point with intrinsic and extrinsic parameters with opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, extrinsic-parameters

i want to find a position of a point with opencv. i calibrated two cameras using cvCalibrateCamera2. so i know both intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. I read that with a known intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, i can reconstruct 3d by triangulation easily. Is there a function in opencv to achive this.I think cvProjectPoint2 may be useful but i don t understand what exactly. So how i can find 3d position of a point.

Thanks.

Comment: This explanation may help you to understand.
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1473

Answer (score 6):

You first have to find disparities. There are two algorithms implemented in OpenCV - block matching (`cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM`) and graph cuts (`cvFindStereoCorrespondenceGC`). The latter one gives better results but is slower. After disparity detection you can reproject the disparities to 3D using `cvReprojectImageTo3D`. This gives you distances for each point of the input images that is in both camera views.

Also note that the stereo correspondence algorithms require a rectified image pair (use `cvStereoRectify`, `cvInitUndistortRectifyMap` and `cvRemap`).